# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in^2x^2}}{n^5+x^4}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the series defined as
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in^2x^2}}{n^5+x^4}
$$
Then I have to show that $S$ converges uniformly and absolutely. I know that I have to use Weiterstrass M-test. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$ \left| \frac{e^{in^2x^2}}{n^5+x^4} \right | \leq \frac{\left| e^{in^2x^2} \right| }{n^5+x^4} \leq \frac{1}{n^5+x^4} \leq \frac{1}{n^5}
$$
where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5} < \infty$. Thus Weiterstrass' M-test says that $S$ converges uniformly and absolutely but I am bit unsure why $|e^{in^2x^2}| \leq 1$? I know that
$$
e^{-i\pi} = e^{i\pi} = -1
$$
Is this the reason? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $|e^{i(\text{anythingreal})}|=1$

Answer (score 2):

For every $\theta\in [0, 2\pi)$, $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ has absolute value $1$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

For a purely imaginary exponent $i\theta$, we have Euler's formula:

$$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$$

thus, since $|x + yi| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and then by the Pythagorean identity,

$$|e^{i\theta}| = \sqrt{\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{1} = 1$$

.